# Update 2 lines with When

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the table below which has similar names in the column 'Nam':

[image]

I need to update the column **status** with the condition below:

If val2 > Val1 (**either** in first line **or** in the second line)-->**both** status should change to "OK"

IF  val2 in both lines are smaller than Val1 (in both lines) -->  Status=False'

I don't know how to update this condition like (if else)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Status = CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.Nam = t1.Nam AND t2.Val2 > t2.Val1) THEN 'OK'
  ELSE 'False'
END
FROM tablename t1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1469764c7bdc2a52fbaa245faa7e83b4).

Comment: Edge case: Does the OP want the `Status` to remain unchanged if `Val1 = Val2` in one or more rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when val2 >= val1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by nam) as num_increasing,
             sum(case when val2 <= val1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by nam) as num_decreasing
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set status = (case when num_increasing = 0 then 'false' else 'ok' end)
    where num_increasing = 0 or num_decreasing = 0
```

Note that this is doing the "inverse" of your logic -- counting the exceptions.

Comment: The `SUM` function is either going to need an `OVER` clause or the query a `GROUP BY`; otherwise this'll error as none of the columns are contained in a `GROUP BY` or aggregate function.

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks but I didn't get it exactly, could you please write it?

Comment: It's not my answer, @arash6657 .